# Light switch with hot pig tail under screw & hot wire in a push-in conncection

Tags: wiring

One hot wire that has the pigtail & it will go under the screw. The other hot wire needs to go in the Push-In Wire Connection. How far in? What if you can see exposed wire once pushed in the hole? This switch controls one overhead light, nothing else as far as I can tell.
The non hot wire will go under the other screw or in the push-in connection.

Answer (score 3):

Add the extra hot to the pigtail and then you don't need the push-in connection, which is less reliable than the screw connection.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using push-in connections altogether. They are unreliable and will cause failures later.

When you need to attach more than 1 wire to a screw, just pigtail with a piece of short wire.  Or you can use the spec-grade switches and receptacles that provide a "screw-and-clamp" method that allow 2 wires under each screw.